# How to fix file permissions on wp-content with official wordpress image for docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

### Problem

---

I'm setting up a Wordpress local environment with docker-compose and the official wordpress image from the docker repository.

I am on windows.

The problem is that I have some premissions issues on the wp-content, and I am not able to upload files from my Wordpress admin panel.
[image: wordpress error unable to create directory]

### What I've already done

---

I checked then the file permissions inside the container, and this was the output:

[image: file permissions in the wordpress container]

As you can see, the owner of my `wp-content` is `root` instead of `www-data`.

**The immediate solution is to open the container's bash and give** 
`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content/`

This of course works, but I don't want to do this process every time I start a new wordpress project. To achieve this I've created a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM wordpress:5.1.1

# install dos2unix (fix problem between CRLF and LF)
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix

# increase upload limit
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "upload_max_filesize = 10M;" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

# fix permissions issues
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And my `entrypoint.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Fixing permissions...
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content/
```

But then I realized that I was overriding the `ENTRYPOINT` of the original wordpress image, and the container exited always with `code 0`.

Then I tried with `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`, and I changed my `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM wordpress:5.1.1

# increase upload limit
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "upload_max_filesize = 10M;" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

CMD chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wpcontent/
```

But I receive always the error that the file or folder doesn't exists.

I've tried to use `CMD` also like this:
`CMD ["chown", "-R", "www-data:www-data", "/var/www/html/wp-content/"]`
 
but without success.

### Question

---

There is a way to run a command **after** the original `ENTRYPOINT`?
Do you know otherwise a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: how do you create the container ?

Answer (score 6):

You can modify your `./entrypoint.sh` script to run the default entrypoint script of the original image after it executes your chown command:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Fixing permissions...
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content/
docker-entrypoint.sh apache2-foreground
```

Comment: Is this best practice though? What if the default entry-point script changes at some point in the future? Encountering this issue now, not sure if I should "extend" the wordpress image using a DockerFile or do as your answer suggests.

Comment: @Patrick Steadman isn't it technically the whole folder that needs to be owned by root?

Comment: @FooBar I think this is up to the individual's use case, setting `wp-content` owned by www-data should be sufficient to allow for upload of media / plugin / theme files through wp-admin, but it creates a new issue for permissions problems when editing files in bind mounts from the docker host, which can be solved by adding your current user in the host to the www-data group (or whatever group has gid 33 on your system). All of this feels very hacky, would love a better solution...I've tried changing the user id that wordpress runs as in the container without success.

Answer (score 3):

From Docker's documentation the command you should be using is `RUN`.

> Don’t confuse RUN with CMD. RUN actually runs a command and commits the result; CMD does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image.

So the line in your Dockerfile should be:
`RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content`

Also, to decrease the number of layers created and the size of your image, I'd chain as many of the `RUN` commands as possible. For example (not tested):

```
FROM wordpress:5.1.1

# install dos2unix (fix problem between CRLF and LF) and increase upload limit
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y dos2unix && \
    touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "upload_max_filesize = 10M;" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content

# fix permissions issues
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh && \
    chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused: Your run command already changes the owner of wp-content. Do I need all the entrypoint.sh related stuff?

Comment: Sadly, this is not going to work. Any changes will be overriden after the build finishes. Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the way the WordPress Docker image is created.

I created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/pull/474) to make the `wp-content` folder belong to `www-data` when it is (or some of its subfolders) shared using a volume.

Before it is merged (it if is), you can create your own WordPress Docker image to integrate my change. Take one of the folder on https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress (choose PHP version, and then webserver parameters).

1. Create a `docker/wordpress` folder in your project.
2. Copy the two raw files (*Dockerfile* and *docker-entrypoint.sh*) from GitHub into that folder.
3. Replace these lines in *docker-entrypoint.sh*:

```sh
        if [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ] && [ "$(stat -c '%u:%g' .)" = '0:0' ]; then
            chown "$user:$group" .
        fi
```

by:

```sh
        if [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
            chown -R "$user:$group" .
        fi
```

Comment: I tried with this git, but the shell file running got an error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752579/entrypoint-sh-line-27-1-unbound-variable

Answer (score 3):

## **Problem**

The parent `docker-entrypoint.sh` is ran after your `Dockerfile` and `entrypoint.sh`, overwritting the permissions you set.

## **Solution**

Custom entrypoint executing a delayed command that sets the ownership after `docker-entrypoint.sh` has ran.

Your **Dockerfile**

```sh
FROM wordpress:php7.4-apache

[...]

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Your **entrypoint.sh**

```sh
# In 10 seconds set the ownership

$(sleep 10 && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/) & 

# Run the parent's ENTRYPOINT and CMD as defined in its Dockerfile
#     (https://github.com/gsusI/wordpress/blob/master/php7.4/apache/Dockerfile)

docker-entrypoint.sh apache2-foreground # run parent entrypoint.
```

> **Note:** Invoking the parent's ENTRYPOINT and CMD manually means that if the parent Dockerfile alters its last two lines this solution might not work properly.
>
> Therefore is recommendable that wheneber updating the your `FROM`, you check the parent's Dockerfile to verify the last two lines are still:
>
> ```sh
> ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
>
> CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
> ```